# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) trying to open a txt

Tags: android, file

im trying to open 4 txt files with an array in each of them. Each array is an array with these dimentions: 12 x (number of days of the month). I need to open this files when i create (start) my app. The values in the arrays are separated by commas (,). The array save a calendar with randoms values. Here is the code where i got the error but i can't resolve:

```
float[][] cargarDatos(float [][] matriz, String file){
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        (*)reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+file));
        String line = "";
        int row = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] cols = line.split(","); 
            int col = 0;
            for(String  c : cols){

                    matriz[row][col] = Float.parseFloat(c);

                    col++;


            }
            row++;
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return matriz;
}
```

Also, i have got this in onCreate method:

```
horasAno=cargarDatos(horasAno,"/anno2017Ordinaria.txt");
```

horasAno is one of the 4 arrays that i need to load with dates

The error that im getting all the time is:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/anno2017Ordinaria.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:418)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
W/System.err:     at com.example.oschertar.calendario.MainActivity.cargarDatos(MainActivity.java:265)
W/System.err:     at com.example.oschertar.calendario.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
```

There is a file with this name in this directory. What am i doing bad? The line 265  is the line that is marked with (*)

Comment: post  code of line 265

Comment: Did you checked run time permissions?

Comment: the code is posted, is the lane that got (*) in the code (reader = new BufferedReader..)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot properly answer your question but will suggest to check these:

- Do you have the permission to read files specified in your Manifest?
- Make sure that file name and directory are correct. I see many people using **`.toString()`** after  **`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`**. I'm not sure why and wonder if it may help.

Comment: I have got this in my manifest:

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I tried use .toString() but im getting the same error.